# "Extra teaching" (compared to the standard contract) for Italian researchers

Tags: mathematics, career-path, teaching, salary, italy

For researchers (RTDa, RTDb, associate and full professors) in Italian universities is it possible to have some "extra" teaching duties (compared to the standard contract)? How would one apply to be assigned these duties? On what tariff are they paid?

A related question about the "standard" teaching duties is in [Teaching duties in Italy for researchers, associate professors, and full professors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/160447/teaching-duties-in-italy-for-researchers-associate-professors-and-full-profess)

Comment: I don't understand why you assume that doing more teaching has a (positive and direct) impact on salary. I'm not really familiar with Italy but I would be surprised if that was the case for tenured faculty anywhere.

Comment: @Roland In my US university there are options to take on extra teaching duties for additional compensation (mainly summer courses or online courses during the regular academic year).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.
In my University, we have a number of hours of mandatory teaching ('included' with the salary), that depends on the level (e.g., 40 hours/year for a RTDa, 60 for RTDb, 120 for professors, and a lot of special exceptions). Only "classroom" hours are counted (so the time for exams, course preparation, student hours, etc doesn't count).
Any additional teaching hours are paid, but they must be authorized in the yearly teaching plan, up to a maximum number (that in our case is 2x the minimum).

The bottom line is that this is legally possible, but a lot depends on each University's regulations.